# Is it possible to enable `emacs-lisp-mode` when org-table-edit-formulas?

Tags: org-mode

The default mode is fundamental, which is not really comfortable to edit elisp code did I miss something ?

Comment: @JeanPierre provides code to switch to emacs-lisp-mode for editing table formulas. You cannot switch to emacs-lisp-mode without 'turning-off' the table-editing commands provided by org-mode. You can add individual features from elisp-mode, or at least keybindings. Are there particular parts of emacs-lisp-mode you want to have access to? We might be able to help you set them up.

Answer (score 1):

A first idea is to to use an *after* [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Named-Functions.html#Advising-Named-Functions) to ensure
`emacs-lisp-mode` is turned on after `org-table-edit-formulas` is run.

```el
 (advice-add #'org-table-edit-formulas :after #'emacs-lisp-mode)
```

However, this does not work well.  Examining the source of the
function (in file `org-table.el`) shows that it turns
`fundamental-mode` on then sets up a few things (variables and
keybindings) that the call to `emacs-lisp-mode` will undo.

We want to call `emacs-lisp-mode` just after (or ideally, instead of)
the call to `fundamental mode` in `org-table-edit-formulas`.  Here's
how to do it:

```el
(defun my--advice-for-edit-formulas (orig-fun &rest args)
  (advice-add #'fundamental-mode :after #'emacs-lisp-mode)
  (apply orig-fun args)
  (advice-remove #'fundamental-mode #'emacs-lisp-mode))

(advice-add #'org-table-edit-formulas :around #'my--advice-for-edit-formulas)
```

We set an *around advice* to `org-table-edit-formulas` whose job is
to:

1. add an *after advice* to `fundamental-mode` to make it run `emacs-lisp-mode`,
2. call `org-table-edit-formulas`,
3. remove the advice to `fundamental-mode`.

This way, `fundamental-mode` calls `emacs-lisp-mode` only when itself
called from `org-table-edit-formulas`.

Now it's possible it would be better to add an option to choose the
mode `org-table-edit-formulas` will use, or to make it automatically
select `emacs-lisp-mode` when the formulas are in elisp.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, but the problem il the same if I active emacs-lisp-mode while interactive. C-c ' is no longer bound to  org-table-fedit-finish and all edits are lost.

Comment: Looking at `org-table.el`, I think that calling `emacs-lisp-mode` after the function cancels a number of things the function has set up (including bindings, but also variables), so this indeed not a viable solution.

Comment: A "brute force" solution could be to copy the function `org-table-edit-formulas` from file `org-table.el`, change the call to `fundamental-mode` by `emacs-lisp-mode` and use that definition to override the one from `org-table.el`.  I think this should work, but may break later when other things change in `org-table.el`.

Comment: How about this? (defun my--advice-for-edit-formulas (orig-fun &rest args)
  (advice-add #'fundamental-mode :after #'emacs-lisp-mode)
  (apply orig-fun args)
  (advice-remove #'fundamental-mode #'emacs-lisp-mode))

(advice-add #'org-table-edit-formulas :around #'my--advice-for-edit-formulas)

Comment: I just tried. It looks fine. many thanks.